# Extracting the address of a requested HTML page from client response (Python3)

Tags: python

I am starting out in Python Network programming.

What I have is code that makes an http request to my metasploitable machine which is running from Oracle VM with IP address 192.168.43.82. I  then stored the response from this machine to a variable called page.

I then created a server with host name "lindani" (my local machine name) and an arbitrary port number 12345. The idea is then a client will make a request to lindani:12345, and I will then serve the page to that client.

Here is the code:

```
from socket import*

def httpRequest(addr,portNumber):
    mysocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 
    mysocket.connect((str(addr), int(portNumber))) 
    request=("GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n").encode('utf-8')
    mysocket.send(request)
    data=mysocket.recv(100000)
    mysocket.close()
    data=data.decode()
    return data

"""
Requesting a page from my metasploitable virtual machine
and storing it as page to serve to a another http client
"""
page=httpRequest("192.168.43.82", 80) 

print("Setting up to serve page to clients")
mySocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) #new socket object
host="lindani" #Get local machine name
portNumber=12345 #allocate a port number for the service
mySocket.bind((host,portNumber))
mySocket.listen(5) # wait for a connect request from client


#wait for a client to make a request then respond
while True:
    c, addr=mySocket.accept() #establish connection with client
    req=c.recv(1024)
    print("Connection successful", addr)
    print(req.decode('utf-8')) # display client details and request on my console
    c.send(page.encode("utf-8"))# send page to client
    c.close()
```

The code works fine and I am able to request lindani:12345 from any broswer in my local machine and I get the metasploitable page displayed.

[Response from lindani:12345 to my broswer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fB4Xt.png)
So far the code can only respond when the main page is requested, it cannot serve a response when you click any of the links. I want to be able to extract the new address when the user interacts with the page and then serve it via the httpRequest fucntion I created. To do this I need to extract "Referer" from the client request (variable req in the code) and then parse it to my httpRequest function. How can I do that?

This is what the request looks like when decoded and printed on the python console:

[Print out of client response. Data I need to extract is highlighted in yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjqHQ.png)

Basically I need help with writing a code that will automatically read the "Referer" part of the response and then respond with that new page.

Comment: What's the URL of the other (non-main) links you're trying to serve? Do they go to lindani:12345/some_page.html? If so, why is the referrer relevant?

Comment: As an example , clicking the twiki link returns Referer: http://lindani:12345/twiki/. I need a way to update the page variable so that I can serve the page when a user clicks a link. Basically I need to link the page variable with the page requested by the browser.

Comment: It seems like what you need is not the referrer, but rather the address parameter of the 'get'. See the first line of the request - it says "GET /twiki/". You should then produce the 'twiki' page.

Comment: But now how do I update my code so that it can read what the address is and automatically get the page. My httpRequest function contains request =("Get /HTTP/1.0\n\n) so far, which requests the main page from metasploitable

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to do a couple of things:

- Pass another parameter, e.g. 'page', to the `httpRequest` method. In that method, instead of doing `GET / HTTP/1.0\n\n` you'll have to do `GET <page_goes_here> HTTP/1.0\n\n`
- Parse the request you're receiving from the client. In the first line, you see something that looks like "GET /twiki/ HTTP/1.1". You'll have to extract the "/twiki'" part, and pass it as an argument to the `httpRequest` function.

Hope it helps.